# Detect contact numbers in different languages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a regex which identify if the contact number is valid or not, but it doesn't work if contact number is in different language.

**Regex:**

```
return /^(\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-.\s]?\(?[0-9]\d{2}\)?[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}/.test(contactString);
```

**Number:**

```
Normal format: +91 9838 838 7373
Different Language (Arabic): +٩١ ٩٨٣٨ ٨٣٨ ٧٣٧٣
```

Now how I can detect that arabic contact number if its valid or not.

Comment: Why not require the user to input using Arabic numerals?

Comment: actually its for chrome extension, in which I try to detect numbers from a site, so it works well for normal format but can't pick different language contacts

Comment: Your best bet may be to map numerals in other languages to their corresponding Arabic equivalents before using your regex. The only other feasible solution I see is to write a regex for each language you are supporting, but that seems too impractical to me.

Comment: yeah true, that's why I need a permanent solution for this, for now I have updated my regex for supporting Arabic.

```/^(\+?([0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,3}))?[-,.\s]*\(?[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,5}\)?[-,.\s]*[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,5}[-,.\s]*[0-9\u0660-\u0669]{1,6}/```

Answer (score 0):

This expression would match all the unicode numbers. Think of this like `\d` on steroids:

`[0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9\u07C0-\u07C9\u0966-\u096F\u09E6-\u09EF\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0E50-\u0E59\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0F20-\u0F29\u1040-\u1049\u1090-\u1099\u17E0-\u17E9\u1810-\u1819\u1946-\u194F\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1B50-\u1B59\u1BB0-\u1BB9\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C50-\u1C59\uA620-\uA629\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA900-\uA909\uA9D0-\uA9D9\uA9F0-\uA9F9\uAA50-\uAA59\uABF0-\uABF9\uFF10-\uFF19]`

We can use that expression to match both phone numbers in your sample.

This expression is doing the following tests:

- Require 4 sets of space delimited digits
- Each set of digits can be 2 to 4 characters long

`(?:[0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9\u07C0-\u07C9\u0966-\u096F\u09E6-\u09EF\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0E50-\u0E59\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0F20-\u0F29\u1040-\u1049\u1090-\u1099\u17E0-\u17E9\u1810-\u1819\u1946-\u194F\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1B50-\u1B59\u1BB0-\u1BB9\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C50-\u1C59\uA620-\uA629\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA900-\uA909\uA9D0-\uA9D9\uA9F0-\uA9F9\uAA50-\uAA59\uABF0-\uABF9\uFF10-\uFF19]{2,4}(?: |$)){4}`

**Live Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/jV5iQ5/1